# Restore Trash (~/.Trash/)?

Tags: finder, trash

I accidently deleted the ~/.Trash/ folder. How I fix this?

I do not want to:

- Restore files currently in the Trash can
- Restore files emptied with the Trash can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Terminal.app and type

```
mkdir ~/.Trash
```

It will create a new empty folder that Mac OS X can use to store trashed files; this won't save any old deleted files from the original .Trash folder you deleted.

Comment: Notice that the new folder you create should probably use permissions that are appropriate. After you make the directory with this suggestion, you should probably also type 'chmod go= ~/.Trash' to ensure that only you have permissions to act on that folder (not "group" or "other" classes of users). In addition, you might need to restart the Finder for the Finder to *notice* that you've created a new .Trash folder (you can restart, logout-login, or use the Force Quit apple menu item to force the Finder to restart).

Comment: The installer CD that came with your computer has an option to reset home folder permissions to thier defaults. That will give it the proper permissions and ACL that it should have.