# How can I find out what is deleting my ~/.Trash folder?

Tags: finder, folders, trash

Some application or action is deleting my ~/.Trash directory. I obviously don't know when this happens, save for the "Are you sure you want to delete..." dialog box.

I can restore the Trash, by restarting the Finder, as [per this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15493/restore-trash-trash), but I would like to figure out what is doing this.

Is there a way to monitor a directory (i.e., .Trash) and determine when it changes? So when my Trash is deleted, I'll know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open Terminal.app
- Type in (or better copy-paste ;): `curl https://raw.github.com/gist/1043757/9b55d3ae174ea40a1ff3b031fec7f87c5a58aa0d/gistfile1.d > usage.d`
- Execute `sudo dtrace -s usage.d`

This will display every file deletion on your system. If you want to only display the deletion of "~/.Trash", add `| grep .Trash` to the last command.

Comment: Do I start this process and leave it running? Then wait for .Trash to show up?

Comment: Yes, you need to keep this running.

Comment: This link is dead, making this answer useless, can anyone update it?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this from the Terminal.app

```
sudo fs_usage -f filesys | grep ~/.Trash
```

will list all processes what accessing Trash - try it - enough click on the Trash icon and you will get tens of line for "Finder".